# Exponential bound on function

Tags: exponential-function, estimation, upper-lower-bounds

I have a cut off function

$$0 \leq \chi(x) \leq 1, \  \chi(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \  |x\pm 1|\leq 1/8 \\ 1, \ |x\pm1| \geq  1/4 \end{cases}$$
and I would like to estimate the function
$$f(x) := \chi(x)xe^{- t(1-x^2)^2} \lesssim  Ce^{-t\omega}$$

Where $t>0$ is fixed and $C,\omega$ are positive constants which need not be sharp and are independent 
of $x$. This should be straight forward, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\chi$ makes the problem unnecessarily difficult ($|f|$ is larger if one would leave out $\chi$) 
$$
|f(x)| \leq |x| \exp(-t(1-x^2)^2) \,.
$$
Therefor, consider $g(x)=: x  \exp(-t(1-x^2)^2)$.

Find extrema of $g$
\begin{align}
0 &\overset{!}{=} g'(x) = \exp(-t(1-x^2)^2) \left[ 1-4tx^2 (x^2-1) \right]
\\
\iff \quad
0 &= x^4 - x^2 - \frac{1}{4t}
\\
\implies \quad
x^2 &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}} \right) 
\\
\implies \quad
x_0 &:= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}} \right) } \,.
\end{align}

Given the extrema $\pm x_0$ it directly follows how to choose the constants
\begin{align}
C &:= x_0
\\
\omega &:= (1-x_0^2)^2 = \frac{1}{4} \left(2+\frac{1}{t}-2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}} \right) \,.
\end{align}